# How to reference a file path from another file in r

Tags: r

I have a series of r scripts which all do very different things to the same .txt file. For various reasons I don't want to combine them into a single file. The name of the input text file changes from time to time which means I have to change the file path on all the scripts by hand. Is there a way of telling r to look for the path name in a text file so I only have to change the text file rather than all the scripts. In other words going from:

df <- read.delim("~/Desktop/Sequ/Blabla.txt", header=TRUE)
to
df <- get the path to read the text file from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Sorted this one in about 5 seconds. Oops

just use source("myfile.txt")

as in:

df <- read.delim(source("~ Desktop/Sequ/Plots/Path.txt"))

Easy